# what does equality to a range mean in excel macros?

Tags: excel

I have to update this code to do a substring or regex match but I don't even understand the code:

```
INDEX(
   $DATA.B$2:B$1501;
   SMALL(
      IF(
         $DATA.$A$2:$A$1501=$B$3;
         ROW($DATA.$A$2:$A$1501)-ROW($DATA.$A$2)+1
      );
      ROWS($DATA.$A$1:$A1)
   )
)
```

The bit that has me scratching my head the most is `$DATA.$A$2:$A$1501=$B$3` what does it mean to test equality of a single cell with a cell range?

In addition, this code is comparing with a string in $B$3, how can I change this to a regex or substring match so that the test is true when $B$3 matches the start of the value in `$DATA.$A$2:$A$1501`?

Comment: Got some data? Maybe with a single cell that has a reasonable result for the macro?

Comment: the data is just strings, it isn't really relevant to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check what does a range return, I did the following.

Filled the cell A1 to F1 with values A,B,C,D,E,F
Placed the cursor on Cell B4
Typed in the formula =A1:F1, it returned B
Placed the cursor on Cell C4
Typed in the formula =A1:F1, it returned C

EDIT: So, if you put value C in cell C3 and put the formula in C4 (=A1:F1=C3), it will return true.

So, I guess the formula gets the value for the current column in the given a range.
Could you give an example by screenshots as to what you want to do?

Comment: The whole process is too complicated to go into detail. Even the macro above isn't complete. I got it in the end and this answer was part of the solution. In the end the biggest problem turned out to be the macro above is an "array macro" and you have to SHIFT-CTRL-ENTER to save it or it doesn't work. I've never seen a more ridiculous and unintuitive concept.

Answer (score 0):

To generalize a little from the answer given, if you do an equality test between an array and a scalar, you get back an array of boolean values. That's why you needed to treat the whole formula as an array formula, because it was manipulating arrays.